# Следующий элемент при нажатии на кнопку JS

Tags: javascript

Следующая задача: мне нужно чтобы на кнопку "Выбрать следующий элемент", оно выбирало каждый раз следующий элемент. Сделал как знал, но оно выбирает только 2 элемент, я не знаю как правильно организовать цикл. Спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homework 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list-items">
        <li>Элемент №1</li>
        <li>Элемент №2</li>
        <li>Элемент №3</li>
        <li>Элемент №4</li>
        <li>Элемент №5</li>
        <li>Элемент №6</li>
        <li>Элемент №7</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="firstElem()">Выбрать первый элемент</button>
    <button onclick="lastElem()">Выбрать последний элемент</button>
    <button onclick="nextElem()">Выбрать следующий элемент</button>
    <script>
        function firstElem() {
            var list = document.getElementById("list-items");
            var item = list.firstElementChild;
                item.style.color = "blue";
        }
        function lastElem() {
            var list = document.getElementById("list-items");
            var item = list.lastElementChild;
                item.style.color = "green";
        }
        function nextElem() {
            var list = document.getElementById("list-items");
            var item = list.firstElementChild;
                item = item.nextElementSibling;
                item.style.color = "red";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Относительно чего следующий? Где фиксируется текущий?

Comment: @Leonid Есть список с id = "list-items", в котором есть элементы, мне нужно чтобы брался первый элемент и от первого к следующему, от него к следующему и так далее, пока не дойдет к последнему элементу. Извините, если некорректно изъясняю  свою 'техническую' мысль!

Answer (score 5):

Нужна независимая внешнаяя переменная, которая будет запоминать номер последнего выбранного элемента:

```js
var index = 0;
function nextElem() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("#list-items li");
  for( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    list[i].style.color = "";
  }
  list[index].style.color = "red";
  
  var demo = index;
  
  index = (index + 1) % list.length;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log( '(' + demo + ' + 1) % ' + list.length + ' = ' + index );
}

function firstElem() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list-items");
  list.firstElementChild.style.color = "blue";
}

function lastElem() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list-items");
  list.lastElementChild.style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-items">
  <li>Элемент №0</li>
  <li>Элемент №1</li>
  <li>Элемент №2</li>
  <li>Элемент №3</li>
  <li>Элемент №4</li>
  <li>Элемент №5</li>
  <li>Элемент №6</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="firstElem()">Выбрать первый элемент</button>
<button onclick="lastElem()">Выбрать последний элемент</button>
<button onclick="nextElem()">Выбрать следующий элемент</button>
```

Другой вариант решения:

```js
var btn = {
  first: document.getElementById('select-first'),
  prev: document.getElementById('select-prev'),
  next: document.getElementById('select-next'),
  last: document.getElementById('select-last'),
}; // (*1)

var items = document.querySelectorAll("#list-items > li");
var index = 0;

btn.first.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index = 0;
  updateSelection();
});

btn.last.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index = items.length - 1;
  updateSelection();
});

btn.next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index = (index + 1) % items.length;
  updateSelection();
});

btn.prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index = (index + items.length - 1) % items.length; // (*2)
  updateSelection();
});

/***/

function updateSelection() {
  var active = document.querySelector('#list-items > li.active'); // (*3)
  
  if( active ) active.classList.remove('active');
  
  items[index].classList.add('active');
}
```

```html
<style>
  #list-items li.active { color: red; }
</style>

<ul id="list-items">
  <li>Элемент №0</li>
  <li>Элемент №1</li>
  <li>Элемент №2</li>
  <li>Элемент №3</li>
  <li>Элемент №4</li>
  <li>Элемент №5</li>
  <li>Элемент №6</li>
</ul>

<button id="select-first">Первый</button>
<button id="select-prev">Предыдущий</button>
<button id="select-next">Следующий</button>
<button id="select-last">Последний</button>
```

**(*1)** [Объекты в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) — их используют для хранения различных данных, но иногда можно просто для удобства, сгруппировать туда схожие элементы.

**(*2)** `index = (index + items.length - 1) % items.length;`

`a % b` возвращает остаток от деления `a` на `b`.

У вас изначально `index` → 0, а `items.length` → 7, Чтобы легче понять, что происходит при клике, полезно где-нибудь пошагово всё записать...

```
(0 + 7 - 1) % 7 =  6 % 7 = 6   // 6 на 7 не делится, остаток: 6
(6 + 7 - 1) % 7 = 12 % 7 = 5
(5 + 7 - 1) % 7 = 11 % 7 = 4
...
```

**(*3)** `document.querySelector('#list-items > li.active')` — querySelector без `All`, возвращает первый соответствующий элемент на странице, или null, если ничего не найдет.

`#list-items > li.active` — элемент `<li>` с классом `active`, который находится непосредственно внутри `id="list-items"`

[CSS - селекторы](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

Comment: Или класс прописать текущему элементу,  типа `chosen`, `active`, `current`). Или атрибут `data-current` завести... И `index=1` указать если как в оригинале..

Comment: + за остаток от деления а не if else =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у вас научился... спасибо)))

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME ))) Да, это прям подкупает ))) (+)

Comment: Новичку тяжко понять за остаток от деления, большое Вам спасибо, за код, сейчас буду переваривать и под свой код подставлять, мне еще и нужно предыдущий элемент искать, начиная от последнего =(

Comment: @ПоляковДенис Добавил ответ и несколько комментариев)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить дочерние элементы узла, с помощью свойства children у вашего ParentNode и дальше, перебираете его получившийся элемент потомков, пример как можно это сделать прикладываю к ответу.

```js
let index = 0;
const nextelement = () => {
  const list = document.getElementById('list-items').children;
  if (index !== 0) {
    list[index - 1].style.color = 'black';
  }
  if (index >= list.length) index = 0;
  list[index].style.color = 'red';
  index += 1;
};

document.getElementById('btnNext').addEventListener('click', () => {
  nextelement()
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Homework 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="list-items">
    <li>Элемент №1</li>
    <li>Элемент №2</li>
    <li>Элемент №3</li>
    <li>Элемент №4</li>
    <li>Элемент №5</li>
    <li>Элемент №6</li>
    <li>Элемент №7</li>
  </ul>
  <button id="btnNext">Выбрать следующий элемент</button>
</body>

</html>
```